# "be n-dimensional vector of variables" vs "be an n-dimensional vector of variables"

Tags: grammar, determiners

For the determiner in English, I learn that they are used in many different situations. For example, **a** is used before a noun. However, sometimes I misuse it. Therefore, I would like to understand it, so I can write my sentence correctly.

For example,

**I have a vector of random variables.**

As I understand, **a** in this sentence is a determiner used to identify the vector, not the random variables. Hence, it is correct to say:

*Let X be **a** vector of random variables*.

Because in this sentence, the determiner **a** refers to the vector X and did not refer to the random variables. Is that correct? if not, then, why?

However, similar to this sentence, I would like to specify the dimension of this vector. So, is it ok to say:

*Let X be **an** n-dimensional vector of random variables.*

Or I must not use the determiner **an** here because **n-dimensional** is plural in its meaning. Is that correct?

So, which sentence is correct?

Comment: About the word, "purple" in your question: is it possible you mean, "plural" [meaning "two or more"]? ... And not just in this question, but also other questions you have recently asked? ... ["Purple" being a color-name]

Comment: Unable to edit it though, sorry.

Comment: **n-dimensional** is an adjective, not a noun. It cannot be plural/singular any more than, say, *long* or *red*

Comment: +1 @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much. I really learn a new thing.

Comment: The main function of a determiner is to mark an NP as definite or indefinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

The essential noun in the sentence is *vector*, which requires an indefinite article:

> I have **a vector**.

This doesn't change if you qualify it with an additional noun phrase, no matter if that additional portion of the noun phrase is singular or plural:

> I have **a vector** (of X and Y).

Nor does it change if you use an adjective in front of it, regardless of the singularity or plurality of the adjective:

> I have **a** (Z) **vector** (of X and Y).

The consideration of the article is based only on the noun itself, not how it's being modified by other things.

---

I say that, but in the one example you gave, the *form* of the indefinite article changes from *a* to *an* because of the vowel sound of *n-dimensional* that comes immediately after it:

> Let X be **an** n-dimensional **vector** of random variables.

But if the adjective started with a consonant sound, you would use *a* again:

> Let X be **a** four-dimensional **vector** of random variables.

Both *a* and *an* are used for a singular noun: *vector* in this case.

---

If *vector* itself became plural, then the indefinite article would be dropped because you would no longer have a single vector:

> I have **vectors**.
>   I have **vectors** of random variables.
>   I have **vectors** that are long.
>   I have single-dimensional **vectors** of random variables.
>   I have n-dimensional **vectors** of random variables.

The consideration of using the indefinite article or not is based only on the use of *vector* or *vectors*.